# How to protect against flash block failure?

Tags: c, linux, file, redundancy, flash-memory

I have a small amount of sensitive data (less than 1K) on flash memory which I would like to protect against some forms of data loss. Most notably, I would like to make sure that the data survives if the flash block it resides on fails.

The obvious answer is to have a backup of the file. Then all I need is to ensure somehow that the two files are located on different blocks. Is there a way to do this?

I'm mostly interested in having this work on Linux, so I'm looking for either a Linux-specific solution, or if there isn't any, a file system specific solution will do too.

EDIT: I'm also open to other approaches of protecting against flash block failure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create extra partition on this memory and put file there.  I would avoid filesystem solution - most filesystem damages start with directory structure. And don't forget about wear leveling controller - you can't be 100% sure, where your data acutally is.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I can figure out is to put a write counter and CRC (optional) on each page, and increment counter on each write.  You can allocate as many pages as you want (2-8?). You overwrite the page with the lowest counter.  If a page write fails (and CRC fails?), overwrite  over the next lowest number page.

When booting, the app only needs to find the page with the highest block number and intact CRC, and carry on from there.

Pages should be multiples of 1K per sector size of your memory.  Check the specs.